# Undefined 'this' in Promise + array. reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, this, reduce

I'm facing a problem since this morning.

**WHAT I HAVE**

Basically, I have a simple class, with an array of files to register:

```
function MyClass() {

    this.filesToRegister = [
        {
            "fileName": "http://tny.im/azk"
        },
        {
            "fileName": "http://tny.im/azk"
        }
    ];
}
```

I have also a simple function, `_contextFunction()` which takes a single `fileToRegister` entry:

```
MyClass.prototype._contextFunction = function(fileToRegister) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        logger.info(typeof this.filesToRegister);
        logger.info('current file: ' + fileToRegister);
        return resolve();
    });
};
```

Note that this function MUST access to the context (the `this`), it's mandatory, and I can't change that.

Finally, I have a utility method, `processArray()`, that can apply a function on each item of an array, all done synchronously:

```
MyClass.prototype.processArray = function(array, fn) {

    let results = [];
    return array.reduce((p, item) => {

        return p.then(() => {

            return fn(item).then((data) => {

                results.push(data);
                return results;
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```

**WHAT I TRY TO DO**

I use this utility method to apply `_contextFunction()` on each item of the `filesToRegister` array:

```
this.processArray(this.filesToRegister, this._contextFunction);
```

It works without problem and execute `this._contextFunction()` on each item of `this.filesToRegister`.

**WHAT THE PROBLEM IS**

BUT, when I try to log `typeof this.filesToRegister` in `_contextFunction()`, the result is `undefined`... After several tests, I concluded that nothing in the context is accessible (neither context attributes nor context methods).

However, if I execute `this._contextFunction()` without the `processArray()` method, I can access to the context (both context attributes and context methods).

**WHAT I THINK**

My guess is that the problem comes from the `processArray()` method, but I don't see where... I tried to log `typeof this.filesToRegister` right in the `processArray()` method, and it works...

To conclude:

- `processArray()` IS able to access to the context.
- `this._contextFunction()` launched 'standalone' IS able to access to the context.
- `this._contextFunction()` launched by `processArray()` IS NOT able to access to the context.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn(item)
```

Calls the function without the context. Use:

```
fn.call(this, item)
```

---

Alternatively pass the method name:

```
this.processArray(this.filesToRegister,"_contextFunction");
```

And then do:

```
this[fn](item);
```

---

How i would do that:

```
class MyClass {
 constructor(){
   this.files = [];
 }
 async add(file){
   await "whatever";
   this.files.push(file);
 }
 multiple(name, array){
   return Promise.all( array.map(el => this[name](el)));
 }
}
```

And then:

```
const instance = new MyClass;
instance.add("whatever");
instance.multiple("add",[1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it...
Will consider your proposition when I'll dive in async/await ;)